# Facebook pixel implementation - code error?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I just implemented our facebook pixel through Google Tag Manager.
And the plugin for chrome "Google pixel helper" can now see the pixel - but it reports an error in the code?

The code was copy/pasted from facebook, so I doubt there is an error in the code.. I just doublechecked, and pasted it again - still, same error..
See attached image, with error message.

See implementation (here)[https://valg.redbarnet.dk]

Hope anyone has an idea what to do from here?

Error

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idlPZ.jpg): [image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, it was a cache error..